# Is there a way to avoid having chained/nested “replace()” items when using an ISO 8601 timezone offset value in a generated column?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, timestamp, timezone, computed-column

I am using MySQL 5.7 and have a table that has the following columns that are being used to store some data that is source from an Apache common log formatted access log; details extracted from a MySQL schema export:

```
`timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`offset` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
`date` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`timestamp` + interval replace(replace(replace(`offset`,'-0','-'),'+0','+'),'00','') hour)) VIRTUAL
`time` time GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`timestamp` + interval replace(replace(replace(`offset`,'-0','-'),'+0','+'),'00','') hour)) VIRTUAL
`hour` int(2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (hour((`timestamp` + interval replace(replace(replace(`offset`,'-0','-'),'+0','+'),'00','') hour))) VIRTUAL
```

As you can see I am storing `timestamp` (`0000-00-00 00:00:00`) and `offset` (`+00:00`) and then using generated columns to calculate, `date` (`0000-00-00`), `time` (`00:00:00`) and `hour` (`0`) values. And this is working well: I get to store the `timestamp` as UTC and then—by storing the `offset` value—I can dynamically get other info in non-UTC form.

But I don’t think the chained/nested [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) items are too hot. The goal is to be able to take an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) timezone offset value like `-0400` or `+1000` as part of an `interval [some value] hour` calculation.

So is there a better way to approach this? I might be able to adjust the way that the timezone offset is stored initially so it is—essentially—exactly what I need for column calculations, but that seems messy and non-intuitive so I would rather use that `+/-[for digit]` format if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading up on [`CONVERT_TZ`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html), it seems like it would be the cleaner method of handling a case like this since I can cut down three (!!!) [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) statements with one like this:

```
CONVERT_TZ(`timestamp`,'+00:00',REPLACE(`offset`,'00',':00'));
```

It still seems a bit sloppy—since I am still dealing with having to convert offset values like `-0400` to `-04:00`—but does work and is cleaner/easier to read and understand.

That said, the above method will fail for offset values such as `+0530`, `+1000` and `+0000`. So instead of that, using the following method—which uses the [`INSERT()` string function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) where colon (`:`) insertion is based on an offset value from the right calculated by the length of the string itself—is cleaner and works for a variety of different offsets:

```
CONVERT_TZ(`timestamp`,'+00:00',INSERT(`offset`,LENGTH(`offset`)-1,0,':'));
```

And these are the results using that with the following sample timestamps and related offsets:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 02:34:58','+00:00',INSERT('+0300',LENGTH('+0300')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 07:50:12','+00:00',INSERT('+0400',LENGTH('+0400')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 09:23:34','+00:00',INSERT('+0530',LENGTH('+0530')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 12:16:56','+00:00',INSERT('+1000',LENGTH('+1000')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 16:07:17','+00:00',INSERT('-0200',LENGTH('-0200')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 20:02:05','+00:00',INSERT('-0700',LENGTH('-0700')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 23:33:03','+00:00',INSERT('-1000',LENGTH('-1000')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 23:33:03','+00:00',INSERT('-0000',LENGTH('-0000')-1,0,':'));
```

And here are the results:

- `2018-05-28 02:34:58` with an offset of `+0300` becomes: `2018-05-28 05:34:58`
- `2018-05-28 07:50:12` with an offset of `+0400` becomes: `2018-05-28 11:50:12`
- `2018-05-28 09:23:34` with an offset of `+0530` becomes: `2018-05-28 14:53:34`
- `2018-05-28 12:16:56` with an offset of `+1000` becomes: `2018-05-28 22:16:56`
- `2018-05-28 16:07:17` with an offset of `-0200` becomes: `2018-05-28 14:07:17`
- `2018-05-28 20:02:05` with an offset of `-0700` becomes: `2018-05-28 13:02:05`
- `2018-05-28 23:33:03` with an offset of `-1000` becomes: `2018-05-28 13:33:03`
- `2018-05-28 23:33:03` with an offset of `-0000` becomes: `2018-05-28 23:33:03`